# how to convert list item to slider when browser is less than 640px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make it slider with pager and touch enabled only in mobile view. I'm not really familiar how to use jQuery/JavaScript so I hope you guys can help me :)

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="images/createacct-icon.png" alt=""><span>Create Account</span></a></div>
    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="images/findgame-icon.png" alt=""><span>Find Your Game</span></a></div>
    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="images/createjoin-icon.png" alt=""><span>Create / Join Team</span></a></div>
    <div class="slide"><a href="#"><img src="images/compete-icon.png" height="75" alt=""><span>Compete & Win</span></a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-family: 'Sintony';
}

.slider .slide {
    float: left;
    width: 22.3%;
    padding: 2% 0;
    background: #191f2e;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.slider .slide:hover {
    background: #151a28;
    transition: background .3s ease;
}

.slider .slide a span {
    color: #c9cbce;
    margin-top: 22px;
    display: block;
}

.slider .slide img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.slider .slide:nth-of-type(2),
.slider .slide:nth-of-type(3),
.slider .slide:nth-of-type(4) {
    margin-left: 3.6%;
}
```

Comment: i want the sliders work when browser is less than 640px width

Comment: If does not have any knowledge on js, use existing ones like owlCarousel or nivo slider or slick js cause they come with support for browsers and any options. Sliders ans carousels are not something strict to deal with cause they could be really customized.

Comment: Yeah but what i want the sliders only work if less than 640px, else the style is floated to left..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have downloaded the slick library from the link that you provided. The "/slick" folder should be in the same directory as your HTML code.

Add the following lines to your `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
```

Add these lines to your `<body>` to import the library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Then your code should be:

```
 <script>

    resizeWindow();
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow);
    function resizeWindow(){
        $('.slider').slick({
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 2500,
                    settings: "unslick"
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 640,
                    settings: {
                        dots: true
                  }
                }
            ]
        });
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: The final result I want to be when the browser have been resized to 640px width or users viewing on their phone is like this [link] (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) "SIngle Item Demo" with pager and touch enable but no next and prev button

Comment: So to clarify, you when the user's browser is less that 640px in width, you would like each of your <img> tags to be in an image carousel, that can be activated by touch? If so, do you already have a library for this or are you looking for that too?

Comment: Correct, I'm still looking for it because all I tried didn't work well. Like this slick, pager/dot not showing..

Comment: I have edited my original answer with a solution. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: getwidth is not working, even my browser is in more than 640px the slick still working and when i refresh the browser it will go back to normal but the pagination is fine now

Comment: Do you have any errors displaying in the console for your browser? What browser are you running the site on?

Comment: Try the code now, I changed the width calculation a little.

Comment: I'm using mozilla firefox and Sublime Text 2 for codes

Comment: Go into your console (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console), and type "window.innerWidth". This should print out the width of the browser. What does it show when your window is maximized?

Comment: my window max width is 1920px

Comment: Width still not working. I guess the problem here is the min.js?

Comment: It looks like there is a way to do this in the library itself. Does this work? I might have reversed it, so try making the size smaller than 640px and see if the slider disappears.

Comment: Just made one other minor change to make sure that the page is loaded before the function runs.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? If so, would you mind marking my answer as correct? Thanks! If not, I am happy to continue to help

Comment: I edited your answer and this time it worked but when i resize again to full width, the slider still working. so i dont know what to do so the slider wont work in more than 640px width.

Comment: Ok I guess this slick is not a good fit on what i need, but if you can still do something let's try it. I do really appreciate your help man you're awesome, I hope we can solve this. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for the late response but I think I have a solution. Give me a sec and I'll update my answer above.

Comment: Alright, the code should work now. The library will work for you, it just requires a bit of playing around, as usually people only want it to work if the screen size is greater than a certain value, unlike what we are doing here.

Comment: I changed one of the imports too, so make sure you change that in your master version.

Comment: It worked for breakpoint but the problem is I need to refresh the browser before it will work

Comment: Hey you think there is other way to make it without using any plugin like this slicker?

Comment: There certainly would, though that would be a project within itself. If I were you, I would stick with this library, as it offers quite a few nice features that would be quite hard to implement without it.

Comment: Try this fiddle i made https://jsfiddle.net/jrvm38e7/ when slick activated try to resize it to full width you will see something not good and try to view it using mozilla you will feel the laggy thing

Comment: It runs fine for me. Maybe check your CPU and RAM usage on your OS?